# Firestore Security Rules - What is it really for?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I don't really get the idea behind the Firestore Security Rules. I can not find it anywhere on documentation.

1. Is it for malicious users who would try to get access our db with reverse engineer the correct config from our apk or ipa or web page?
2. Or it is for not messing the db with large development team?

This questions comes up my mind because first option should not my issue because I tought I already pay for this service while publishing my app with Firebase sdk's.

Is it my responsibility to creating a not-reverse-engineerable application for keep secure the db?

This questions conflicts in my mind.

Comment: Also, What's wrong with my question? Am I have to ask this type of questions from StackExchange? It is rude to giving thumbs down without explanation.

Comment: 1: without rules anyone can just modify your backend data as they wish by sniffing the requests your app is doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a traditional three tier application you'd have a server sitting between your database and the user's devices. Your code on that server would do things like sign-in the user, ensure they're authorized for the operation they're trying to perform, and then perform that operation.

With Firebase, many of your operations can be performed by having the devices communicate directly with the backend services (like database or file storage). This means you'll move the actual business logic of your operation into client-side code. And with Firebase Authentication, sign-in is also handled without server-side code from you. But then where does the check for a user's authorization go?

This is where Firebase's security rules come in. They're like a pre-processor on the server, that ensures the operation the user is trying to perform is authorized according to the rules you specify.

Members of your development team will likely be collaborators on the Firebase project, and use a mechanism that bypasses the security rules to access the backend services (like the Firebase console, or one of the Admin SDKs that run with administrative privileged).

I highly recommend reading the Firebase documentation on [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules), which contains this simple statement about it:

> Firebase Security Rules stand between your data and malicious users.